# FF / CSS / select option font size how?

Tags: html, css, firefox

There were similar questions in the past but I ask it anyway because many things changed. See the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/32sn0L37/1/

```
<select>
    <option>hello1</option>
    <option>hello2</option>
    <option>hello3</option>
</select>

select { font-size: 300%; }
```

The font size of the option texts in the dropdown list changes in all major browsers (IE, Chrome, Opera) except in Firefox.

Any idea how to increase it in FF too from CSS or JS? Thanks.

Comment: Your JSFiddle works in Firefox 47.0. Let me just update it... Okay, it works in 47.0.1 as well. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Screenshot here: http://i.imgur.com/pxGsqec.png

Comment: @Alexis: My problem is opposite. It works in Chrome but not in FF.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: FF 49 and it gives the result on the screenshot on LInux and on Windows 10 too, see here: http://i.imgur.com/pxGsqec.png

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. I've just updated to version 49.0.1 and I'm on Windows 10. I'm a bit confused as to what the icon in the top left is though: my Firefox is a clean install. Could it be that some theme or something similar that you've installed is causing this problem? http://i.imgur.com/vPNLBMh.png

Comment: BTW, I'm testing it of course with a new and empty profile with default settings without any addons. I have the same issue on Ubuntu 16 x64 and Windows 10 too.

Comment: Windows 10 screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/jG3ISts.png

Comment: I have finally tracked down the following: 1) I delete the C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla folder on a newly installed Windows 10. 2) Start FF and open the JSFiddle and it works good. 3) Close FF and then reopen the same and it doesn't work.

Comment: The same problem happens for the second FF start on another machine with Win7 x64.

Comment: No repro for me on Firefox 49 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: I reported the FF bug and it came out that it's the soon to be default E10 bug, see more here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1308466